# How to view logs even if the app has been disconnected in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I need to see the logs when the app is closed (removed from memory). But doing so disconnects the app and therefore I can't see print statements in IntelliJ console. I thought `adb logcat` would still show the logs, but it stops logging upon disconnect too. Can I achieve what I want without using background services?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Connect your device to your machine and run `flutter logs`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked. For people who got the message "No supported devices connected" after running the command., you need to be in the flutter project folder in order to see the logs. There is an open issue related to that https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47996