# How can I receive my app Logs after killing it?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator, firebase-cloud-messaging, genymotion

To test my flutter app background notifications, I need to still receive its logs in the terminal when my app is terminated/killed (not in background).
Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796791/how-to-view-logs-even-if-the-app-has-been-disconnected-in-flutter)?

Answer (score 20):

Open terminal and run `flutter logs` command.